# Mass updating/install on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, remote-access

I currently use LogMeIn to remotely manage a bunch of computers around the country. However, I am curious as if there is a way to make updating on them automatic and install and make system changes on ALL the machines remotely.

This is not a question about LogMeIn. This is a more general based question.

I also should mention, I would like to also expand this to Adobe, Java, and other related services. Is there a way to push CLI to the targeted machines? These machines are also not all in a corporate network. They consist of many networks for many businesses and home users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kaseya](http://www.kaseya.com.au/) is an agent that you install on each client machine. It periodically calls back home (to the IT office) to check if it has jobs to run, information to feedback.

Kaseya allows:

- Customisable scripts, but a strong community of all sorts of tasks
- Built in patch management interface/utility

Basically, you can run whatever you want on a bunch of unrelated, geographically sparse computers with the click of a button... or a schedule :)

Answer (score 0):

Where I previously worked, our company's Desktop IT team used something like [Altiris](http://www.symantec.com/client-management-suite?fid=endpoint-management) to manage OS updates installation, make client system changes, and for imaging desktop machines, among others.

**UPDATE**: The Altiris software was used on Windows machines connected via a domain (AD). Given the recent update on the question, this is probably not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem (except I use GoToAssist).

So far the best solution we've come up with is to simply **not** update the computers in the field and use a remote desktop server/terminal server instead. This has greatly lightened the burden of keeping remote system management. Any critical applications are hosted on our Citrix XenApp farm, and local systems are used for little more than web browsing.

It can still be a pain to manage the systems though. I've had some luck with [Meraki](http://meraki.cisco.com/). You'll need to install an agent on each PC manually, but once you've finished that you can push MSIs and send CLI commands to remote PCs.

Aside from essentially creating a botnet out of your remote PCs (which I consider trying every day), there isn't a clear cut solution to this problem.